# What is wrong with my code, mysql, PDO prepare delete statement?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

Why my code is not working. Help, I don't see any wrong. If I use user_id=$current_user instead of user_id=:current_id, it works. But I need to prepare for security reason. Help please.

```
<?php
$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = '**';
$password = '**';
$dbname = '**';
try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", "$username" ,"$password" , 
        array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo" There was an error with the connection";
}

$current_user=$_POST['users_id'];//get user id

include 'db_tag.php';
$stmt=$db->prepare("DELETE FROM object_sign WHERE user_id=:current_id");

$stmt->bindParam(":current_id",$current_user,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute(); 

?>
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: in firebug, it said NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Check in the response/preview the error

Comment: Try to remove `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false` from PDO constructor

Comment: @conan,you can check my answer & let me know your feedback so I can help you to resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@conan, Use below code that I have mentioned & you need to check below points with this code.

**1)** Print $current_user id to make sure id correctly appeared or not,Also I have put condition if post contain user id then only query being executed.

**2)** I have put exception so you can check errors through exception message.

```
<?php
include 'db_tag.php';

$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = '**';
$password = '**';
$dbname = '**';

try {
     $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", "$username" ,"$password" , 
        array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

    if(isset($_POST['users_id'])) {
        $current_user=$_POST['users_id'];//get user id

        $stmt=$db->prepare("DELETE FROM object_sign WHERE user_id=:user_id");

        $stmt->bindParam(":user_id",$current_user);
        $stmt->execute(); 
    } 
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: After I use your exception message, Error: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined, but $current_user=$_POST['users_id']; has no problem, I test echo $current_user, it is good. So why the parameter was not defined in my case.  hmmm, my table contain more than one same user_id, will that cause the problem? But if I use user_id=$current_user, I have no problem to delete. So, in my case, what have I done wrong?

Comment: @conan,I have edited my answer & change param so please check now with above code again & let me know if still any issues over there.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is the name, The name have to be match. user_id have to match :user_id

Answer (score 1):

Is $current_user an integer or string. If string try PDO::PARAM_STR instead of PDO::PARAM_INT

```
$stmt->bindParam(":current_id",$current_user,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

If still its not working try this

```
//$stmt->bindParam(":current_id",$current_user,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute(array(:current_id"=>$current_user));
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your second way is working too. Your first way, PHP Weblineindia figure out the problem, the name I need to match the name I need to bind. so user_id have to match :user_id, cannot be :current_id, Thanks for your time.